# How to use special characters on keyboard without pressing shift key?

Tags: keyboard, windows-10, special-characters, autohotkey, shortcut

How can I use number keys on top of the keyboard just for special characters like (@#$) without pressing the shift key to use that? For example, when pressing the num2 key, just show @; I searched about that and understood can do that with AutoHotkey, but I don't find a script to do that, which is no problem. I just want to use numeric keys located at the top of the keyboard. Use that just for special characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Steps :*

1-Go to [AoutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) website  and download AutoHotKey **its size is
about 3 megabytes.**

2-After installing AutoHotKey, right-click on the desktop, select the new AutoHotkey
script, and select that to create a new fileName.ahk

3-Copy this on your  .ahk file:

```
`
1::!
2::@
3::#
4::$
#CommentFlag // 5::%
6::^
7::&
8::*
9::(
```

0::)
'::"
`

4-Save your file and close it.

5-Right-click on your file and click run Script, or just double click.

If you want to close it, you can do that on task manager.

**every time your pc shot down or restarted,ed you should run that script again**

your AuotoHotKey flie shuold be like this =
[image]
Meanwhile, you can do other cool things : [Read This](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/10-cool-autohotkey-scripts-make/)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer after you find it.